# Prove that a functor $F:C_{(X,\leq)}\to C_{(Y,\leq)}$, being $(X,\leq),(Y,\leq)$ partially ordered sets, is just an application that is monotone.

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

I'm a computational engineer starting with a course of Introduction to Category Theory, and perhaps is extremely basic what I'm asking but I'm trying to learn how to make proofs in category theory working with the very basic concepts, but I just can't figure things out right now. Can you help me?

Thank you!

> Prove that a functor $F:C_{(X,\leq)}\to C_{(Y,\leq)}$, being $(X,\leq),(Y,\leq)$ partially ordered sets, is just an application that is monotone. If $F,G:X\rightrightarrows Y$  are two
>   monotone applications, prove that there is a natural transformation of $F$ to $G$ if and only if, for each element $x\in X$, $F(x)\leq G(x)$.

Comment: HINT: given two objects $a,b \in X$, you have $$a \le b \Leftrightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(a,b) \neq \emptyset$$ and in such a case you have that $\operatorname{Hom}(a,b) = \{ a \to b \}$ is a singleton.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Important fact: given two objects $a,b \in X$, you have $$a \le b \Leftrightarrow \operatorname{Hom}_X(a,b) \neq \emptyset$$ and in such a case you have that $\operatorname{Hom}(a,b) = \{ a \to b \}$ is a singleton. Clearly this holds for $Y$ as well.

Now, recall that functors are defined on morphisms. Whenever you have a map $F:X \to Y$, being a functor means that if you have a morphism $a \to b$, then you have automatically a morphism $F(a \to b)=F(a) \to F(b)$. In other words
$$a \le b \Rightarrow F(a) \le F(b)$$
So $F$ is a covariant functor if and only if $F$ is increasing, and $F$ is a contravariant functor if and only if $F$ is decreasing.

In a similar way you can prove the second statement. Given two functors $F,G:X \to Y$, a natural transformation $F \to G$ is a family of morphisms $\{ F(x) \to G(x) \}_{x \in X}$ (such that all squares commute). This means that $\forall x \ \ F(x) \le G(x)$ (by the important fact).

Finally, if you have some square in an ordered set, then this is automatically commuting, since all $\operatorname{Hom}$ sets are singletons. So, you don't have to care about commutativity of squares.